# Receive file stream through REST web service ResponseEntity<byte[]>

Tags: java, matlab, file, rest, stream

I wrote a method to send file as byte array through rest web service and on client I would like to receive this file as stream (the client is a matlab application that uses java code).
When I send I file also than 300MB I receive heap error on matlab because heap memory is setted on 356MB instead in eclipse is 1024MB. It is possilbe to use stream for ResponseEntity received so to store every byte at a time? Or I must necessarily increase Matlab heap memory on 1024?. I have this code on server:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(value = "/file", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public  ResponseEntity<byte[]> getAcquisition(HttpServletResponse resp,@RequestParam(value="filePath", required = true) String filePath){
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    File toServeUp= null;
    try{
        toServeUp=new File(filePath);
        if (!toServeUp.exists()){
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
            LOG.error("Threw exception in MatlabClientControllerImpl::getAcquisition : File doesn't exists!!");
            String message = "ERROR: Could not retrieve file on server, check the path!";       
            return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(message.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        }else{
            try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(toServeUp);) {
                resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream"); 
                resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+toServeUp.getName()+"\"");
                Long fileSize = toServeUp.length();
                resp.setContentLength(fileSize.intValue());
                outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int read = 0;
                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>("ok".getBytes(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
                LOG.error("Threw exception in MatlabClientControllerImpl::getAcquisition :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
                String message = "ERROR: Could not send file!";     
                return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(message.getBytes(("UTF-8")), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
            }finally{
                //close the streams to prevent memory leaks
                try {
                    if (outputStream!=null){
                        outputStream.flush();
                        outputStream.close();           
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
                    ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
                    LOG.error("Threw exception in MatlabClientControllerImpl::getAcquisition :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
                    String message = "ERROR: Could not close stream.!";     
                    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(message.getBytes("UTF-8"), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
                }
            }   
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        LOG.error("Threw exception in MatlabClientControllerImpl::getAcquisition :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
        String message = "ERROR: Error in the path, check it!";     
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(message.getBytes(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

On the client I have:

```
@Override
    public Response getFile(String serverIp, String toStorePath, String filePath){
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> responseEntity = null;
        try{
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            responseEntity  = restTemplate.getForEntity(serverIp + "ATS/client/file/?filePath={filePath}", byte[].class, filePath); 

            if (MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN.toString().equals(responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType().toString()))
                return new Response(false, false, new String(responseEntity.getBody(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")), null);
            else{
                Path p = Paths.get(filePath);
                String fileName = p.getFileName().toString();
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(toStorePath+"\\"+ fileName);
                fos.write(responseEntity.getBody());
                fos.close();
                return new Response(true, true, "Your file has been downloaded!", null);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
            return new Response(false, false, "Error on the client side!" , errorResponse);
        }
    }
```

Actually, all the file is in `responseEntity` and it throws heap exception.
Thanks, best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use setBufferRequestBody(false) generate in turn a StreamingClientHttpRequest which open the connection when getBody() is called.

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);     
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
```

After that, I think just using a FileSystemResource as your request body will do the right thing.

Comment: maybe I don't undestand well. I use `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
   SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
   requestFactory.setBufferRequestBody(false);     
   restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
   responseEntity  = restTemplate.getForEntity(serverIp + "ATS/client/file/?filePath={filePath}", byte[].class, filePath);` 
but receive the same error